# How do I make it so Discord select menu doesn't return to placeholder?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this code that creates a select menu in discord.js and uses it to edit the message. However, every time I select an option, it goes back to the placeholder instead of staying on the page I selected. How can I make it so that it stays on the option it selected? In the code example, I would click "Admin" and after I click it, it updates and goes back to "Make a selection". So how would I make it stay on "Admin" with the checkmark next to it?

I tried almost every single update and reply method I found on the discord.js guides. Apparently, it works when I do something like normal replies, but not whenever I try to edit the message instead of a reply, it returns to the placeholder.[image]

I tried every update and reply method and it doesn't work. Apparently, when I do a reply, it works and would stay at the selected option, but not when I try to edit the message.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the message that has the select menu, if you edit it, it will reset to the default form, to make it stay on the option you are choosing you need to reply to the interaction, not update it, or if you really want to update it then get the select menu from `<Interaction>.message`, get the option you chose and make it default, now the thing is that everyone will see that option as default, if the select menu is in an ephemeral message then you can make it like this.